# how to access to response data index by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, vue.js

hello friend how can i access to data index from data response using javascript. here is my code:
HTML

```
<label id="user">USER</label>
```

and here is javascript

```
this.$store.dispatch('Login',this.value_login)
  .then(response => {
    if(response!='') {
      this.login_result = new Array();
      this.login_result = response;
      document.getElementById('user').innerHTML= this.login_result.firstname
    }
   });
```

and here is the data i get from response

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdKyU.png)

thank you for helping

Comment: What do you mean by data index? Can you also share the response that you get back on that call? Note `this.login_result = new Array();` is redundant as it gets overwritten by: `this.login_result = response;`

Comment: Ok i had edit my question and add picture of the data into my question

Comment: A copy paste of the data instead of image would have been much better (for next time) - but thanks for this too.

Comment: See the enter (newline) character in between pass and word of your response? That will break json

Comment: Ok this is copy past:[{"id":1,"firstname":"Neng","lastname":"vang","email":"nengvang@gmail.com","password":"1234"}]

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? get the id?

Comment: i want to get the firstname and lastname

Comment: `this.login_result[0].firstname` and `this.login_result[0].lastname` as `this.login_result` is an array according to your api response [{...}]

Comment: ok thank you i have got it already.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the response of the API call was an array as per the screenshot and comment:

```
[
  {
  "id":1,
  "firstname":"Neng",
  "lastname":"vang",
  "email":"nengvang@gmail.com",
  "password":"1234"
  }
]
```

The question was asking to retrieve the firstname and lastname, so the solution was to use the index 0 on the resulting array as follows:

`this.login_result[0].firstname` and `this.login_result[0].lastname`

Comment: Hi all friend, Now it's working correctly, so thank you for you helping